# Ignore exception from generator

Tags: python, exception, for-loop, generator

By using `os.walk()` to traverse the folder like this:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    do something...
```

There will throw a exception: `UnicodeDecodeError`, I want to ignore the exception and continue, and I tried this:

```
try:
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        do something...
except Exception, e:
    logging.exception(e)
    continue   # this continue is illegal
```

as the comment says, the `continue` in exception part is a syntax error. Is there a way to ignore the exception and continue to traverse?

The exception is thrown from `os.walk()`, so put the `try/except` within `for` can not catch the exception. The `os.walk()` will return a *python generator*, How to catch the exception within it?

Answer (score 6):

**Update:**

I originally thought that the error was being raised by the `do something...` code.  Since it is actually being raised by `os.walk`, you will need to do something a little different:

```
walker = os.walk(path)
while True:
    try:
        subdir, dirs, files = next(walker)
    except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
        logging.exception(e)
        continue
    except StopIteration:
        break

    do something...
```

Basically, this is taking advantage of the fact that `os.walk` returns a [generator object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator).  This allows us to call [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on it and thereby have control over the iteration during each step.

The `subdir, dirs, files = next(walker)` line attempts to advance the iteration.  If a `UnicodeDecodeError` is raised, it is logged and we continue on to the next step.  If a `StopIteration` exception is raised, it means that we are done walking the directory tree.  So, we break the loop.

---

Since `continue` needs to be inside the loop, you will need to move the `try/except` block in there as well:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    try:
        do something...
    except Exception, e:
        logging.exception(e)
        continue   # this continue is *not* illegal
```

Also, doing:

```
except Exception, e:
```

has been deprecated.  You should be using the `as` keyword in place of `,`:

```
except Exception as e:
```

While you're at it, you should replace the generic `Exception` with the specific `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
```

You should always try to catch the most specific exception that you can.  Otherwise, you run the risk of accidentally catching an exception that you did not mean to handle.

Comment: Also better to catch the specific UnicodeDecodeError rather than any general Exception "do something" might raise.

Comment: The exception throw from `os.walk()`, not within the `for` loop, so the try/except do nothing with that exception.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation while iterating over links using Beautiful Soup. This is the code I wrote for that:

```
class suppressed_iterator:
    def __init__(self, wrapped_iter, skipped_exc = Exception):
        self.wrapped_iter = wrapped_iter
        self.skipped_exc  = skipped_exc

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            try:
                return next(self.wrapped_iter)
            except StopIteration:
                raise
            except self.skipped_exc:
                pass

class suppressed_generator:
    def __init__(self, wrapped_obj, skipped_exc = Exception):
        self.wrapped_obj = wrapped_obj
        self.skipped_exc = skipped_exc

    def __iter__(self):
        return suppressed_iterator(iter(self.wrapped_obj), self.skipped_exc)
```

An example:

```
class IHateThirteen:
    ''' Throws exception while iterating on value 13 '''

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.it = iter(iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        v = next(self.it)
        if v == 13:
            raise ValueError('I hate 13!')
        return v

# Outputs [10, 11, 12, 14, 15]
exception_at_thirteen = IHateThirteen([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
print(list(suppressed_generator(exception_at_thirteen)))

# Raises ValueError
exception_at_thirteen = IHateThirteen([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
print(list(exception_at_thirteen))
```

You can fix your code by using above code:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in suppressed_generator(os.walk(path)):
    do something...
```

Above code can be extended more to have callbacks per skipped exception types if needed, but it may be more pythonic to use [iCodez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27613629/7771076) in such a case.

Answer (score -3):

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    try:
        do something...
    except Exception, e:
        logging.exception(e)
        continue   # this continue is illegal
```

Comment: This does not answer anything, it only copies a piece of code from the original question.